# Why is the processor not waiting?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, seconds

I'm trying to do a game of turns. The player passes the turn to IA and vice-versa. The problem is, the processor runs everything too fast and I want make a `WaitForSeconds` sometimes. In the following example I want to make the processor wait for 3 seconds before using the coin, but it just ignores the command and goes to the method `Player1Turn()` without waiting for 3 seconds. What's wrong?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Exemplo : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (IATurn == true)
        {
            StartCoroutine(UseCoin());
            //Do some stuff
            Player1Turn();
            IATurn = false;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator UseCoin()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        MyMana--;
    }

    void Player1Turn()
    {
        //Do stuff;
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't that be `yield return new WaitForSeconds(3000);` the seconds are in milliseconds not single integers..

Comment: @MethodMan No, [per the docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds-ctor.html). It's a float for number of seconds.

Comment: then looks like the OP needs to do  `yield WaitForSeconds(3);` vs new @DiegoBittencourt read the following http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds-ctor.html

Comment: @MethodMan No, you're probably just looking at the Javascript example, but the question is about C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In clear words, look at the flow of your code,

In `Update` it executes `StartCoroutine(UseCoin());`, then immediately executing pointer jumps into `UseCoin` method, where it finds from the first line that rest of the line will execute after 3 seconds, so it will be back after 3 seconds, meanwhile execute rest of the code.

[image: Visual]

Hope you understand.

Comment: Yes, now I understand how it works. I put some conditions on `Update()` and now the code are working fine! Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 2):

When you call `StartCoroutine(UseCoin())`, Unity starts executing the coroutine. Once it gets to `yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);` (in this case the very first thing that happens!) the coroutine is temporarily stopped and control returns to `Update`. The rest of `Update` is executed, which includes `Player1Turn()`. After 3 seconds, Unity starts the coroutine again: `MyMana--` is executed and the coroutine finishes.

It seems like the problem here is just that you expected `StartCoroutine` to wait until the coroutine is done before continuing to execute `Update`, but it doesn't wait.

If you move `Player1Turn();` into the coroutine after the `WaitForSeconds`, it will happen after the wait has been completed.

---

Note that it's actually very useful that `Update` doesn't have to wait for the coroutine to finish: this means that any continuous logic like UI or animations will keep on happening while the game logic waits for whatever amount of time is necessary. If you understand how to use coroutines properly, you don't have to write the usual countdowns and such that Valery's answer suggests.

Comment: Thanks man, it helped me a lot to understand how coroutine works!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not good at Unity, but it seems that you are trying to do some weird stuff. Let me explain why I think so: Update method is called every frame(!), so your code looks a bit strange (try to imagine your code in Update method called 60 times per second). For such problem as time counting in Unity you have Time.deltaTime (which will also make you fps-independent, because it's real time spent for frame) - you can just sum them in Update and when this sum is more than 3s - then do your logic.

Comment: Avoiding coroutines altogether works (I coded like that in Unity for a while before realizing how useful they can be) but I recommend learning how they work. Even if you end up not liking them, at least you know about the extra tool.